# Reversing list with strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list,

```
last_names = [
'Hag ', 'Hag ', 'Basmestad ', 'Grimlavaag ', 'Kleivesund ',
'Fintenes ', 'Svalesand ', 'Molteby ', 'Hegesen ']
```

and I want to print i reversed, so 'Hegesen' comes first, then ' Molteby' and at the end 'Hag'.

I have tried `last_names.reverse()`, but that returnes None..

Any help?

Comment: try `print(last_names[::-1])`

Comment: I'm just guessing about usage here, but including a space after each last name is not good. The space belongs to last name usage, not definition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.reverse` returns `None` because it reverses *in-place*:

```
>>> last_names = [
... 'Hag ', 'Hag ', 'Basmestad ', 'Grimlavaag ', 'Kleivesund ',
... 'Fintenes ', 'Svalesand ', 'Molteby ', 'Hegesen ']
>>> last_names.reverse()
>>> last_names
['Hegesen ', 'Molteby ', 'Svalesand ', 'Fintenes ', 'Kleivesund ', 'Grimlavaag ', 'Basmestad ', 'Hag ', 'Hag ']
```

To do this in an expression, do `last_names[::-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, `.reverse` reverses the list in place, a more pythonic way to reverse a list and return it, is to use [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
>>> list(reversed([1,2,3]))
[3, 2, 1]
```